How to read a json with pug NodeJs?
I am sending from node to my pug template a json in the response like this:
  res.render("memberships", {
     title: "DashRoc - Membresías",
     settings: JSON.parse(req.session.settings)
  });
  //JSON
  {
     "expirepass": false,
     "memberships": {"view":true}
  }

but when I try to read it in pug it says that the 'view' object is not found.
  if settings.memberships.view
     p You have permission to see the membership

I tried to print the content of settings in the console and the result is positive, I can access the 'view' object.
  script.
     console.log(!{settings}) // result -> {"expirepass":false,"memberships":{"view":true}}

but in pug it won't let me access beyond 'memberships'.

What is the error message?

@Konrad https://imgur.com/zTxtqEE

The error says that settings.memberships is undefined. Try checking what is a type of settings

@Konrad i print the 'settings' object in the console and this was the result: https://imgur.com/ZSRMpgm The 'settings' object was sent in the response res.render('memberships',{'settings':JSON.parse(req.session.settings)}) and req.session.settings is generated from the database result where I save req.session.settings = bdresult[0].settings (RowDataPacket).
